# Change php path

Tags: php, installation

I've a server running Centos 5. Yesterday I upgraded php to 5.4.10 throught remi repository.
Operation was successful ( I've checked updated information in phpinfo())
Today I figured out that php launched from shell, displays a different version (5.2.16). This version is the previous one.
If I do

```
which php
```

output is: /usr/local/bin/php
while the new php 5.4 binary is /usr/bin/php

From what I understood, php was manually compiled in the system and there are no source installation files around.

How can I change the path  usr/local/bin/php to /usr/bin/php.
I dont'k know where to look for.

Comment: Just try removing the PHP that was installed to `/usr/local`.

Comment: I've already done it, but with no luck. php from command line stopped working until I created a symlink ln -s /usr/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php. Btw symlink is not a solution because other commands rely on that path such as pear command. so I need to change this path at the root (I'd like to know where this path is stored in).

Comment: Just log out and log back in.

Comment: @MichaelHampton logged out without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into documentation and  others great Linux stuffs I've found the solution.
All depends from $PATH environment variable, specifically from the order of the directory listed in.

```
#original $PATH
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin
```

So, I moved /usr/local/bin at the end of the string, and everything start working again:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Now I've to make this edit persistent, because export instruction expires with session end.